# Payable function with additional value attached (web3, React)

Tags: solidity, web3js, react

I'm making a React frontend for an open-source blockchain protocol for tokenized hedge funds. So the question is how to provide the payable function that requires some other value attached (n this case, it's uint _usdEthBasis)?

The case is the user wants to send ether to a contract by this payable function with the uint _usdEthBasis number attached.

```
// [INVESTOR METHOD] Issue a subscription request by transferring ether 
// into the fund
// Delegates logic to the InvestorActions module
// usdEthBasis is expressed in USD cents.  For example, for a rate of 300.01, 
// _usdEthBasis = 30001

function requestSubscription(uint _usdEthBasis)
    whenNotPaused
    payable
    returns (bool success)
  {
    var (_ethPendingSubscription, _totalEthPendingSubscription) = 
    investorActions.requestSubscription(msg.sender, msg.value);
    investors[msg.sender].ethPendingSubscription = _ethPendingSubscription;
    totalEthPendingSubscription = _totalEthPendingSubscription;

    LogSubscriptionRequest(msg.sender, msg.value, _usdEthBasis);
    return true;
  }
```

I tried this one, but I got the error:

> Unhandled Rejection (Error): Invalid number of parameters for
>   "requestSubscription". Got 0 expected 1!

```
    <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
      <h4>Issue a subscription request by transferring ether into the fund</h4>
      <div>
        <label>Amount of ether to subscribe</label>
        <input
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={event => this.setState({ value: event.target.value })}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>usdEthBasis</label>
        <input
          value={this.state.usdEthBasis}
          onChange={event => this.setState({ usdEthBasis: event.target.value })}
        />
      </div>
      <button>Subscribe</button>
    </form>
```

Here is the onSubmit function:

```
    onSubmit = async event => {
      event.preventDefault();

      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

      this.setState({ message: 'Waiting on transaction success...' });

      await fund.methods.requestSubscription().send({
        from: accounts[0],
        usdEthBasis: this.state.value,
        value: web3.utils.toWei(this.state.value, 'ether')
      });

      this.setState({ message: 'You have been entered!' });
    };
```

Comment: @MaheshRajput Please add your reply as an answer.

Comment: Done @Ismael, my comment posted as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to pass parameter as `this.state.value` in`await fund.methods.requestSubscription(<here you forgot to pass>)`.

Answer (score 0):

`await fund.methods.requestSubscription()`
 -- here you need to specify the unit argument you need to pass, it's just like a method call, pass the arg in requestSubscription(< args>)

Moreover, if you want to pass the sender, `{from: sender_addr}`in the args space, separated by a comma.